# wireless usb disk?

Tags: wireless-networking, bluetooth, usb-flash-drive

My dream is to have a "USB disk" I can access (wifi or bluetooth) without taking it out of my wallet. Does something like this exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no USB sized device I am aware of that does this right now, however I can think of a way you can do this.  Firstly I do not know your exact scenario which you would like to use this under, so I will make a few assumptions so I can give you something that will work.

Running a USB key like this would be a problem because USB keys require a 5 volt power source to function properly. a USB flashdrive proper is not up to this challenge however moving up to a stand alone usb drive that also has a network port and tcp/ip capability is just what the doctor ordered here.   It may not fit in your pocket, but it will work just fine working from a fixed location like where your wireless router is situated.

Lacie makes a 1TB drive that has a built in ethernet port.

You could miniaturize this type of solution with a gumstick computer running linux ,an IP stack, wireless adapter and a USB interface you can plug a thumbdrive into. You would need to carry a battery with you if you wanted it to work from inside your pocket however.

Answer (score 3):

You could turn your Symbian Phone into a "Network Attached Storage" device with SymNAS (http://www.telexy.com/Products/ProductInfo.aspx). Of course, your phone is already accessible via bluetooth.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is [Eye-Fi](http://www.eye.fi/index.html) SDHC memory cards, but they are powered by the camera. If you have a camera that supports SDHC cards and can fit in your pocket, then you're golden.